# use Json in .net MVC model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I'm refactoring my code and moving business logic from the controller to the model, but it seems that Json functionalities are not available in the model.
It is so strange that I'm sure it's me that I'm missing something.

In the controller I can do

```
var myList = (from myItem in db.MyModel
              where (myItem.code == "somecode") 
              select myItem);
JsonResult jList = Json(myList);
```

As I move this code into the model I have an error on line

```
JsonResult jList = Json(myList);
```

saying that "The name 'Json' does not exist in the current context.

I have the same using statements in both model and controller, (System.Web.Mvc should be the one for Json functionality) and by right clicking Json i do not have the "resolve" option.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

In this case [`Json()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) is the method of Controller base class.

You can try using JSON.Net, or some other serialilzer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, anyway I prefer to go with Craig W, this way I do not need to link another library.

Comment: If you don't want to add another library, you can use built-in `JavaScriptSerializer` class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx My understanding is that's what's used for JsonResult.

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out the `Json(myList)` call you're making is to a method on the base controller class. As you're no longer executing that code in a class that derives from `Controller` the method is no longer available.

However, that method is just a convenience wrapper around the creation of a JsonResult. To replicate the functionality outside of a controller you can use:

```
JsonResult jsonResult = new JsonResult()
{
    Data = data,
    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet
};
return jsonResult;
```

Comment: Thank you, it is exactely what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your controller inherits from the Controller abstract class. 
This code snippet is from my base api controller but it will be the same theory (ApiController => Controller)

```
public class BaseApiController : ApiController
{
    public Code.CodeService CodeService { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs the Base Controller and sets up the global properties that need to  be accessible by other Controllers.
    /// </summary>
    public BaseApiController()
    {
        CodeService = new Code.CodeService();
    }

}
```